# Error only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expression can be used as a statement

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have this list:

```
List<Utilizadores> LU = new List<Utilizadores>();
```

and when i try to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LU.Count(); i++)
{
    if (LU[i].getUsername() == username)
    {
        LU.Remove[i];
        return true;
    }
}
```

it gives me this error:

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expression can be used as a statement"

What can it be?

Comment: `LU.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: Side note: It's probably a wiser idea to use `LU[i].getUsername().Equals(username, StringComparison...)`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)

Comment: Another side note: `LU.Count` instead of Linq's `LU.Count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `RemoveAt` - remove item at *given index* (`i` in your case); current `LU.Remove[i];` is a *syntax error*

```
 ...
 LU.RemoveAt(i);
 return true;
 ...
```

Comment: Oh... Sorry and at the same time tanks my bad.